# TSQL Sum is giving wrong result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to get sum of data but I am getting wrong result

Example 1[image]

Example 2[image]

Result when doing sum

[image]

AS you can see from Example 1 -  where p_key is 11020145101617761 and LC_Amount is 8.4 , 168 , -176.4  the sum of this is 0

similarly in Example 2 - where p_key is  1102014510615767 and LC_amount is
-571067.53, 543873.84 , 27193.69 the sum of this is also 0

but  in the result when I do group by with p_key , I am not getting 0

I don't understand what is the reason behind this.

Comment: I dont understand, In your question your result show 0 for that id. So where is the error?

Comment: look for p_key 1102014510615767 its giving result -6.18456397205591E-11 which is very close to 0 but not exactly 0

Comment: I see now, but your example doesnt include the data for those so how can we check what is causing the error. Change to numeric or decimal

Comment: numeric and decimal does not work as well, round() works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an example of IEEE-754 rounding errors. Note the numbers are all very close to zero, but juuuuuust off, see the exponent.

Wrap your `SUM` in `ROUND()`:

```
SELECT ROUND( SUM( LC_Amount ), 10 )
```

...should do it.

Comment: thank you very much this works for most of them but still it is not exactly 0 with p_key = 11020145101615767 result LC_AMOUNT_SUM is -1E-10. is there a way I can get exactly 0

Comment: @mb1987 Change the second argument from `10` to a smaller number, such as 4 or 5, assuming that's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because float is not <strike>true</strike> exact numeric type.
Try to use `DECIMAL(10,2)` type to avoid round errors.

There is a lot info about float type in the web.

Comment: Right solution, wrong reasoning. `float` is just as valid a type in general as `decimal`, and `decimal` does not get rid of all rounding errors. (What's `1/3`? What does that make `1/3 * 3`?) But `decimal` would have avoided these particular rounding problems and does seem appropriate here.